# Returning active or inactive based on payment data from other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm a beginner in python and I hope you could help me with my problem.

I have the following dataframe:

```
 account_id contract_id date_activated  term_months 2020-08-01 00:00:00 2020-09-01 00:00:00 2020-10-01 00:00:00 2020-11-01 00:00:00 2020-12-01 00:00:00 2021-01-01 00:00:00 2021-02-01 00:00:00 2021-03-01 00:00:00 2021-04-02 00:00:00
0   12454545    ADD 2020-08-24  11  620.984848  620.984848  620.984848  620.984848  0.0 0.0 0.00    0.00    0.00
1   12454545    ADFGG   2021-02-01  12  0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.0 0.0 687.94  687.94  687.94
2   1646468 ASDADGAD    2020-08-03  7   1504.700000 1504.700000 1504.700000 1504.700000 1504.7  1504.7  1504.70 0.00    0.00
3   5454555 ADGA    2020-08-10  8   528.000000  528.000000  528.000000  528.000000  528.0   528.0   0.00    0.00    528.00
4   48654   GHDG    2018-10-18  6   100.000000  100.000000  100.000000  0.000000    0.0 0.0 0.00    0.00    0.00
```

I want the following output:

```
 account_id contract_id date_activated  term_months status  2020-08-01 00:00:00 2020-09-01 00:00:00 2020-10-01 00:00:00 2020-11-01 00:00:00 2020-12-01 00:00:00 2021-01-01 00:00:00 2021-02-01 00:00:00 2021-03-01 00:00:00 2021-04-02 00:00:00
0   12454545    ADD 2020-08-24  11  Active  620.984848  620.984848  620.984848  620.984848  0.0 0.0 0.00    0.00    0.00
1   12454545    ADFGG   2021-02-01  12  Active  0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.0 0.0 687.94  687.94  687.94
2   1646468 ASDADGAD    2020-08-03  7   Inactive    1504.700000 1504.700000 1504.700000 1504.700000 1504.7  1504.7  1504.70 0.00    0.00
3   5454555 ADGA    2020-08-10  8   Active  528.000000  528.000000  528.000000  528.000000  528.0   528.0   0.00    0.00    528.00
4   48654   GHDG    2018-10-18  6   Inactive    100.000000  100.000000  100.000000  0.000000    0.0 0.0 0.00    0.00    0.00
```

Each account can have one or more contracts. I have an external data which should be set manually to determine the current date, in this case it's "May 1, 2021".

I need to identify each contract as either "Active" or "Inactive" based on the payments (headers with date) and the term in months. This will be in a new column "status". There is a grace period of 4 months for those that have stopped paying.

If a contract has been paying every month (no non-payment) equal to its term and has already ended its term before the current date (based on term_months), it will considered as "Inactive". Refer to contract_id "ASDADGAD".

If a contract has been paying regularly and has not expired as of the current date, it will be considered as "Active". Refer to contract_id "ADFGG".

If a contract has not yet expired (based on the term) and there are no payments on and before the current date but it is still within four months, it is still considered as "Active". Refer to contract_id "ADD" and "ADGA".

But, if the non-payments are beyond four months for a contract, it will be considered as "Inactive". Refer to contract_id "GHDG".

Here's the dictionary for the result:

```
{'account_id': {0: 12454545, 1: 12454545, 2: 1646468, 3: 5454555, 4: 48654},
 'contract_id': {0: 'ADD', 1: 'ADFGG', 2: 'ASDADGAD', 3: 'ADGA', 4: 'GHDG'},
 'date_activated': {0: Timestamp('2020-08-24 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2021-02-01 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2020-08-03 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2020-08-10 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2018-10-18 00:00:00')},
 'term_months': {0: 11, 1: 12, 2: 7, 3: 8, 4: 6},
 'status': {0: 'Active',
  1: 'Active',
  2: 'Inactive',
  3: 'Active',
  4: 'Inactive'},
 datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 1, 0, 0): {0: 620.984848484848,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 1504.69999999999,
  3: 528.0,
  4: 100.0},
 datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 1, 0, 0): {0: 620.984848484848,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 1504.69999999999,
  3: 528.0,
  4: 100.0},
 datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 1, 0, 0): {0: 620.984848484848,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 1504.69999999999,
  3: 528.0,
  4: 100.0},
 datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 1, 0, 0): {0: 620.984848484848,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 1504.69999999999,
  3: 528.0,
  4: 0.0},
 datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 1504.69999999999,
  3: 528.0,
  4: 0.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 1504.69999999999,
  3: 528.0,
  4: 0.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 687.94,
  2: 1504.69999999999,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 687.94,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 2, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 687.94,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 528.0,
  4: 0.0}}
```

Comment: What if the current date is much further away from the last column's date, from the df. 
Like If it is July 1st 2021, what do I consider for dates between April 2nd (last column) and July 1st 2021?

Comment: Based on my current data, it will never happen. The current date is always within the available columns.

Comment: 12454545 is active after non-payment of 5 months. Is the output supposed to be this?

Comment: I'm very sorry. I meant to set the current date as "March 1, 2021". This may have confused you. Based on this, 12454545 is still active. But, if the current date will be set as "April 1, 2021", it will be inactive.

Comment: The current date logic not very clear. So if the current_date is set to March 1, 2021, we ignore all the columns that are after march 1 2021, is it?

Comment: Yes. That's right. We ignore the columns after the current date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the imports to handle the dictionary that you gave in the question - let's call the variable dicti

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
```

Let's convert it to a dataframe and make everything "Active" in the beginning for a new status column

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dicti, orient='index').T
df["status"] = 'Active'
```

Then we iterate over the rows to find out who's terms have ended. after_start_date_indices gives the columns that are after the date_activated for each row

```
all_date_columns = df.columns[5:]
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    start_date = row[2]
    after_start_date_indices = all_date_columns>=start_date
    start_date_index = np.where(after_start_date_indices==True)[0][0]
#     if your going to calculate from the first time he pays
#     start_date_index = df.columns.get_loc(row[5:][row[5:]>0].index[0])-5
    if row['term_months'] < df.shape[1]-5-start_date_index:
        df.loc[index, ['status']] = 'Inactive'
```

Finally people who haven't paid through the grace period - last 4 months

```
df.loc[df.iloc[:,df.shape[1]-4:].sum(axis=1)==0, ['status']]='Inactive'
```